Gettig error on installing the Phonepe in React native
I am trying to integrate the Phonepe in react native application by using below command.
npm i https://phonepe.mycloudrepo.io/public/repositories/phonepe-mobile-react-native- sdk/releases/v2/react-native-phonepe-pg.tgz

Above command i got from Phonepe payment gateway integration website.https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/react-native-sdk-integration-standard
But i am getting below error.Please guided me how we can integrate the Phone pe.
 Unknown command: "i https://phonepe.mycloudrepo.io/public/repositories/phonepe-mobile-react- native-sdk/releases/v2/react-native-phonepe-pg.tgz"

Trying to integrate Phonepe Payment gateway

The command should be npm i https://phonepe.mycloudrepo.io/public/repositories/phonepe-mobile-react-native-sdk/releases/v2/react-native-phonepe-pg.tgz without whitespace after sdk
